# Ubuntu 14.04 Can Access LAN but not Internet (Verizon Fios)

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I have been struggling with this for quite some time. I am away from home a lot and have an Ubuntu 14.04 server (SSH, HTTP, Transmission, Plex) running with the proper ports forwarded through my Verizon Fios router (FiOS-G1100). We recently had a snow storm and for some reason the box that converts fiber optic data to coax had to be replaced by Verizon. Ever since this time, my server can only intermittently connect to the internet (and I can only intermittently connect to it from outside the network). The Fios router is 192.168.1.1. I get ping results like this (where 192.16.31.23 is verizon.com):

```
$  ping -i 15 verizon.com | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done
Wed Feb 10 15:50:08 EST 2016: 64 bytes from 192.16.31.23: icmp_seq=142 ttl=59 time=9.62 ms
Wed Feb 10 15:50:23 EST 2016: From 192.16.31.23 icmp_seq=143 Destination Net Unreachable
Wed Feb 10 15:50:38 EST 2016: 64 bytes from 192.16.31.23: icmp_seq=144 ttl=59 time=10.0 ms
Wed Feb 10 15:50:53 EST 2016: From 192.16.31.23 icmp_seq=145 Destination Net Unreachable
Wed Feb 10 15:51:08 EST 2016: From 192.16.31.23 icmp_seq=146 Destination Net Unreachable
```

...and so on. Here is a traceroute result:

```
$ traceroute 192.16.31.23
traceroute to 192.16.31.23 (192.16.31.23), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  0.387 ms  0.564 ms  0.738 ms
 2  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  0.925 ms !N  1.111 ms !N  1.288 ms !N
```

The only reason I can run these commands is because I have TeamViewer set up on one of my Windows machines and I can reliably SSH through there. I can successfully ping and connect to other machines on the LAN. My server is assigned to a static IP both through the router and in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.5
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

The ports are forwarded correctly. My iptables are flushed. The rest of the computers on the LAN have no problem accessing the internet. What is going on here? Is there anything else I can do to diagnose this better? Could this be a router issue? I looked through all of the config on the router and didn't see anything limiting my server. I have also found that rebooting the router fixes the issue for about a minute (this is variable) before problems start to occur again.

Some other output that may be helpful:

```
$ sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

$ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.370 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.342 ms

$ traceroute 192.168.1.1
traceroute to 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  0.484 ms  0.709 ms  0.945 ms

$ ping 192.168.1.4
PING 192.168.1.4 (192.168.1.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.423 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.431 ms

$ traceroute 192.168.1.4
traceroute to 192.168.1.4 (192.168.1.4), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 ...
30  * * *

$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

EDIT: Edited for clarity.

Comment: I don't understand the problem as you've described it. You can't access the internet from the Ubuntu server or you can't access the Ubuntu server from the internet? If the former, what does port forwarding have to do with it?

Comment: @joeqwerty, sorry for being unclear, I can't access the internet from the Ubuntu server AND I can't access the Ubuntu server from the internet, intermittently.

Comment: You should show the result of the traceroute to a website or 8.8.8.8 (with option -n ). But it looks like your internet provider have some trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually was able to solve this out of luck. It turns out there was a switch on the network with the same IP as the router, which was causing the issue. I think the switch got reset in a power surge and took on its default configuration (as a router). I was only able to figure it out by happening upon the admin screen for the switch instead of the router when I navigated to 192.168.1.1 from a X11 Tunneled window off of the server. Lesson learned. The server wasn't even routed through the switch, interestingly.